# Is it possible to express attention as a Fourier convolution?

Tags: convolution, attention

Convolutions can be expressed as a matrix-multiplication (see e.g. [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11172/2444)) and as an element-wise multiplication using the Fourier domain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

Attention utilizes matrix multiplications, and is as such $O(n^2)$. So, my question is, is it possible to exploit the Fourier domain for attention mechanisms by turning the matrix multiplication of attention into a large convolution between the query and the key matrices?