# How is the convolution operation connected to neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, convolution

I've been reading up on the convolution operation and neural networks. I understand that the convolution operation is defined as:

$$(f * g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) g(t-\tau) d \tau$$

The convolution operation has some properties, such as commutativity, associativity, etc.

How is the convolution connected to neural networks? How do we use this operation in a CNN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convolution operation performed by most CNNs that you will find (on the web) assumes that the signals/functions are discrete and 2-dimensional (e.g. images can be viewed as 2-dimensional discrete signals), although this does not have to be the case. In fact, 1D and 3D convolutions are also implemented in several deep learning libraries (see [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/) for an example).

The equation in your post describes the convolution operation for 1-dimensional continuous signals with domain $\mathbb{R}$ (sometimes called the *time domain*, hence the usage of the letter $t$), so we use an integral that goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

An equation that better describes the common 2D convolution operation performed by CNNs is the following

$$S(i, j)=(K * I)(i, j)=\sum_{m=-M}^M \sum_{n=-N}^N I(i+m, j+n) K(m, n), \tag{1}\label{1}$$

where

- $S(i, j)$ is the convolution of the signals $I$ (e.g. an image) and $K$ (e.g. the kernel) evaluated at the coordinates (or points of the domain) $(i, j)$, so $S$ is the function that results from the convolution of $I$ and $K$
- $(K * I)(i, j)$ is just another notation for $S(i, j)$, which emphasizes that the convolution is performed between $K$ and $I$, and $*$ is the convolution operation
- $K(m, n)$ is the value of the function $K$ (in the context of neural networks and image processing, this is often known as the *kernel*, hence the $K$, or *filter*) evaluated at $(m, n)$
- similarly, $I(i+m, j+n)$ is the value of the function $I$ (e.g. the image) evaluated at $(i+m, j+n)$

So, essentially, equation \ref{1} is telling us that the value of the convolution between $I$ and $K$, denoted by $S$, evaluated at $(i, j)$ is a sum of products, where the factors are $I(i+m, j+n)$ and $K(m, n)$, where the values of $m$ and $n$ depend on $M$ and $N$, which could also be equal, and typical values would be, for example, $1$ or $2$, so equation \ref{1} could be written as follows

$$S(i, j)=(K * I)(i, j)=\sum_{m=-1}^1 \sum_{n=-1}^1 I(i+m, j+n) K(m, n), \tag{2}\label{2}$$

If you expand the summations, you will get

$$S(i, j)= 
I(i-1, j-1) K(-1, -1) + I(i-1, j) K(-1, 0) + \dots + I(i+1, j+1) K(1, 1)$$

This is essentially a 2D [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) or, equivalently, an element-wise multiplication followed by the addition of those multiplications.

Another important thing to note is that the convolution of $I$ and $K$ evaluated at $(i, j)$ uses the values of $I$ with respect to the points $(i, j)$.

Moreover, in a 2D convolutional layer of a CNN, we do not just compute $S(i, j)$, but we compute $S(i, j)$ for all possible values of $i$ and $j$, which are typically the coordinates of the image (in the case of the first layer).

Finally, the equation \ref{2} actually describes what is known as the *cross-correlation operation*, which is exactly the same as the convolution operation, but we use $+$ instead of $-$ in $I(i+m, j+n)$. In practice, in the context of CNNs, it doesn't really matter whether you use the $+$ and $-$, given that the kernels $K$ are learned. However, the convolution operation and the cross-correlation would be different in the case the kernels are not symmetric, but identical in the case they are. You can read more about this topic [in this answer that I had written a while ago](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/22000/2444).

You should probably also read [this chapter](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html) that more thoroughly describes all these operations. There are also other answers that I had written in the past that could be useful, such as [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/23831/2444), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12510/2444), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/21401/2444), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/21967/2444), and/or [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/21874/2444). By the time you have understood all these answers, you will also have understood the convolution operation and how it is related to CNNs.