# Is the 3d convolution associative given that it can be represented as matrix multiplication?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, convolution, linear-algebra, principal-component-analysis, convolutional-layers

I'm trying to understand if a 3D convolution of the sort performed in a convolutional layer of a CNN is *associative*. Specifically, is the following true:

$$
X \otimes(W \cdot Q)=(X \otimes W) \cdot Q,
$$

where

- $\otimes$ is a convolution,
- $X$ is a 3D input to a convolution layer,
- $W$ is a 4D weights matrix reshaped into 2 dimensions,
- and $Q$ is a PCA transformation matrix.

To elaborate: say I take my 512 convolutional filters of shape ($3 \times 3 \times 512$), flatten across these three dimensions to give a ($4096 \times 512$) matrix $W$, and perform PCA on that matrix, reducing it to say dimensions of ($4096 \times 400$), before reshaping back into ($400$) 3d filters and performing convolution.

Is this the same as when I convolve $X$ with $W$, and then perform PCA on that output *using the same transformation matrix as before*?

I know that matrix multiplication is associative i.e. $A(BC)=(AB)C$, and I have found that convolution operations can be rewritten as matrix multiplication.

So my question is, *if I rewrite the convolution as matrix multiplication, is it associative with respect to the PCA transformation (another matrix multiplication)*?

For example, does $X' \cdot (W' \cdot Q) = (X' \cdot W') \cdot Q$, where $X'$ and $W'$ represent the matrices necessary to compute the convolution in matrix multiplication form?

To try and figure it out, I looked to see how convolutions could be represented as matrix multiplications, since I know matrix multiplications are associative. I've seen a few posts/sites explaining how 2D convolutions can be rewritten as matrix multiplication using Toeplitz matrices (e.g. [in this Github repository](https://github.com/alisaaalehi/convolution_as_multiplication/blob/master/Convolution_as_multiplication.ipynb) or [this AI SE post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11172/2444)), however, I'm having trouble expanding on it for my question.

I've also coded out simple convolutions with a $W$ matrix of $4 \times 3$, an $X$ matrix of $4 \times 2$, and using `sklearn`'s PCA to reduce $W$ to $4 \times 2$. If I do this both ways, the output is not the same, leading me to think this kind of associativity does not exist. But how can I explain this with linear algebra?

Can anyone explain whether this is or is not the case, with a linear algebra explanation?